# Searching trough NSDictionary using search bar

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, uisearchbar

I would like to know how I am able to `filter` `NSDictionary` using `searchBar`?

I declared 2 variables `var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()` and `var filteredUsers = [NSDictionary?]()`

Now I am trying to filter them like this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
        let username = user!["username"] as? String
        return(username?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    }
        if searchText != ""{
            shouldShowSearchResults = true
            followUsersTableView.reloadData()
        }else{
            shouldShowSearchResults = false
            followUsersTableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

And I do the `updateSearchResults`:

```
filteredUsers.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = (usersArray as NSDictionary).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
        filteredUsers = array as! [String]

        self.followUsersTableView.reloadData()
```

But for some reason it is not filtering it.

How should I do it?

Comment: You need to filter on the keys of the dictionaries: "SELF.dictionaryKeyToFilter CONTAINS[c] %@".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whipped this out in playground, works fine

```
var usersArray = ["Adam", "Eve", "Ace", "Michael"]
var filteredUsers: [String]
var searchText: String = "a"

filteredUsers = usersArray.filter { $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
print(filteredUsers)
```

PS I would change your if statment to check if !filteredUsers.isEmpty rather than searchText. because you really only want to reload if that array has something to show, regardless if the searchText is nil or not

[image]

Comment: Value of type 'NSDictionary?' has no member 'lowercased'

Comment: It's an array of dictionary, not an array of strings.

Comment: just change it to $0.user.username or $0.user["username"] as? String then the rest. Depends on if its a dictionary or a PFObject etc